Linearizing a Fractional Program
I am working to linearize this fractional program below. $z$ is the result of linearizing the product of two binary variables $x_{ik}$ and $x_{jk}$', the decision variables. $p$, $q$ and $z$ are auxiliary variables I introduced to linearize the original formulation. And $w$ is $\geq 0$ is exogenously provided. Those are two binary vars where they are equal when node $i$ and node $j$ are assigned to different clusters $k$ and $k'$. The last thing is that those products are only ever considered when $k=k'-1$, accounting for a natural ordering of the clusters.
The original formulation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{K-1} \sum_{k'=k+1}^{K} \frac{\left| \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in V} w_{ij} x_{ik} x_{jk'} - \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in V} w_{ji} x_{ik} x_{jk'} \right|}{ \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in V} w_{ij} x_{ik} x_{jk'} + \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in V} w_{ji} x_{ik} x_{jk'} }
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
s.t.
 \sum_{k=1}^{K}x_{ik} = 1 \forall i \in V
\end{equation}
Where I am now
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{K-1} \sum_{k'=k+1}^{K} \frac{p+q}{ \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in V} w_{ij} z_{ijkk'} + \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in V} w_{ji} z_{ijkk'} }
\end{equation}
subject to:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^{K} x_{ik} = 1, \quad \forall i \in V \\
&p - q = X - Y \\
&p \geq X - Y \\
&q \geq Y - X \\
&p \geq 0, \quad q \geq 0 \\
&z_{ijkk'} \leq x_{ik} \\
&z_{ijkk'} \leq x_{jk'} \\
&z_{ijkk'} \geq x_{ik} + x_{jk'} - 1 \\
&x \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}

Please make clear what are the optimization (decision) variables. if $p,q,w$ are not optimization variables, and $w \ge 0$,then this can be handled as an MISOCP; using a convex modeling tool such as CVXXPY or CVX, this would then be something like sum(sum((p+q)*inv_pos(denominator))). or is not using such a tool, the Second Order Cone constraints underlying inv_pos can be explicitly entered.

Apologies @MarkL.Stone I clarified and added the original formulation for more context. $p,q,w$ are not decision variables and $w$ is $\geq 0$.

The $p \ge X-Y$ and $q\ge Y-X$ constraints are implied by the others and can be omitted.

Consider "compact linearization": multiplying the original equality constraint by $x_{jk'}$ yields $\sum_k z_{ijkk'} = x_{jk'}$, which dominates your $z_{ijkk'} \le x_{jk'}$.  You can then also omit the $z_{ijkk'} \ge x_{ik}+x_{jk'}-1$ constraints.

Your p and q are functions of decision variables, and therefore not input data. Therefore the MISOCP formulation in my first comment does not apply.

@RobPratt apologies, I believe that $p-q = X-Y$ shouldn't have been introduced. I was attempting to linearize the absolute value in the numerator by splitting out the positive and negative part into constraints.

You need $p-q=X-Y, p\ge 0, q \ge 0$ for that linearization but not the other two inequalities.

Ahh thank you @RobPratt. I also like your idea for compact linearization. That reduces the messiness when I implement this. Thanks a lot!

To linearize the (simplified) objective
$$
   \min f= \frac{p}{\sum_i w_i \delta_i}
$$
with $\delta_i \in \{0,1\}$ you can form:
$$\begin{aligned}
\min\>&f\\
  &f\sum_i w_i \delta_i = p
\end{aligned}$$
and linearize the constraint. This comes down to linearizing terms $f\delta_i$ which is a standard continuous times a binary variable (or an "or" constraint) (see e.g. How to linearize the product of a binary and a non-negative continuous variable?).
Using a global quadratic solver, you can also use $f\sum_i w_i \delta_i = p$ directly. Another approach for this kind of fractional objective is using Dinkelbach's algorithm (see: http://egon.cheme.cmu.edu/Papers/MILFP_YouCastroGrossmann.pdf).

Would be interesting to see whether the resulting MILP formulation would be faster or slower to solve than the MISOCP formulation having fewer binary variables.

@MarkL.Stone I would guess the MIP is faster. But you never know without trying. (And my success rate in these guesses is close to 50%).

I have "withdrawn" the MISOCP formulation on account of seeing that p and q are not input data.

Thank you @ErwinKalvelagen for your response. I'm not sure I immediately see why this is a valid reformulation. The link you sent says that you can introduce a new variable to equal the product of the continuous and binary variable but I'm not seeing how that's equivalent to setting it equal to the numerator in this case. Apologies for my lack of understanding

@Statsnoob  $ f\sum_i w_i \delta_i = p$ can be written as $\sum_i w_i g_i=p$ with $g_i=f \delta_i$.

@ErwinKalvelagen thank you for the further explanation! This seems to work great
